# Linq and lambda expression not being performed on DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

on my DB I have some objects that have a GUID and a list of GUIDS.

Initially, I was writing in linq (and I'd prefer to keep it that way, really), but I started using lambdas since there was more support online.

EDIT: I'll explain what I'm trying to do since it looks like I'm going for a convoluted result.

I have a list of Guids: RequiredGuids.
On my DB, I have a list of objects that point to a TemplateVersion GUID and that are connected between themselves through some tags. Here is an example:

```
 public class PkgDB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public System.Guid PkgGuid { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string PkgType { get; set; }

    public Guid TemplateVersion { get; set; }
}


public class PkgTagDB
{
    // Key FK
    //[ForeignKey("PkgDB")]
    public Guid PkgGuid { get; set; }
    // Key
    public string TagType { get; set; }
    // Key
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

A pkgTag can indicate that aa pkg is extended by another pkg, kind of like OOP. This happens by having a tag like "GuidMain, extendspkg, GuidExtension".
Hence, the guid of the extension pkg is in the value field.
Now, my RequiredGuids refer to the TemplateVersion Guids of the pkgs.
What I want is to select the pkgs that have extensions that point to the RequiredExtensions templates.

From the DBContext, I get an Iqueryable object that is kind of like the following:

```cs
var example = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            RootGuid = new Guid("1748b2f2-207a-4200-8901-68e48987563c"),
            ExtTemplateGuids = new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("f3b7649c-d0b0-4e0a-bdf9-6d08d3bfe194"),
                new Guid("fd667311-cdc2-4f51-8c41-e023cd6ceb05"),
                new Guid("019eaccb-71d2-4a3e-adcb-6baae9615c08")
            }
        },
        new
        {
            RootGuid = new Guid("1748b2f2-207a-4200-8901-68e48987563c"),
            ExtTemplateGuids = new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("f3b7649c-d0b0-4e0a-bdf9-6d08d3bfe194"),
                new Guid("fd667311-cdc2-4f51-8c41-e023cd6ceb05"),
                new Guid("019eaccb-71d2-4a3e-adcb-6baae9615c08")
            }
        }
    };
```

For completeness: the object comes from the following query

```cs
var example = 
    from tag in DBContext.PkgTagDB
    where tag.TagType == SystemTags.IsExtendedByPkg
    join pkg in DBContext.PkgDB on tag.PkgGuid equals pkg.PkgGuid
    group tag by tag.PkgGuid into tags
    select new
    {
        RootGuid = tags.Key,
        ExtTemplateGuids = from ext in tags
                            join extPkg in DBContext.PkgDB on ext.Value equals extPkg.PkgGuid.ToString()
                            select extPkg.TemplateVersion
    };
```

On my application, I get a list of GUIDS, RequiredGuids, and I want to select only the object whose list of GUIDS contains the RequiredGuids list.

The problem I have is that all of the conditions I'm writing don't get executed on the DB, but they work fine if I throw a ToList in there.

```cs
// Doesn't work
var extension14 = example.Where(t2 => RequiredGuidExtensions.All(ext => t2.ExtTemplateGuids.Any(t => t == ext)));
// Works
var extension15 = example.ToList().Where(t2 => RequiredGuidExtensions.All(ext => t2.ExtTemplateGuids.Any(t => t == ext)));
```

When executed in c#, these two expressions work the same, but when the DB expressions get involved they start behaving differently.
I don't know how to produce a "not working" example, since the c# code works. It's just when working with a queryable that it stops working.

Also, the condition seems to work just fine in a foreach:

```cs
foreach (var pkg in example)
{
    bool t2 = RequiredGuids.All(ext => pkg.ExtTemplateGuids.Any(t => t == ext));
}
```

Thanks to phuzi's suggestion, I tried calling a tolist on extension14, the not working example, and it throws the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'ext => CollectionResultExpression:
ProjectionBindingExpression:ProjectionBindingExpression: 1
ElementType:Guid
.Any(t => t == ext)' could not be translated.
```

Anybody ever encountered anything like this?

Comment: The queries won't actually be executed against the database until you enumerate the results of the `IQueryable`. Calling `ToList()` is one way to do this, as is performing a `foreach` over it.

Comment: From question I can't understand where is EF Core context and where is local collections. Also specify which ORM and which version you are using. Also post real classes no mocks.

Comment: @phuzi If I call a ToList directly, I get the exception I added on the question

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried being more clear in the question now. From the DB I get an object that is build just like that in the example

Comment: That's a different issue and means that a portion of your expression `pkg.ExtTemplateGuids.Any(t => t == ext)` cannot be converted to appropriate SQL. You would have to rework your query to be translatable or, like in your second example `example.ToList()...`, perform the query in .Net, however, this means that the entire data set will be fetched first.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to look into how to rewrite it. The web doesn't seem to be too helpful in this regard tough

Answer (score 0):

Check the following query:

```cs
var extensionsCount = RequiredGuidExtensions.Count;

var query =
    from tag in DBContext.PkgTagDB
    //join pkg in DBContext.PkgDB on tag.PkgGuid equals pkg.PkgGuid // maybe not needed
    where tag.TagType == SystemTags.IsExtendedByPkg
        && DBContext.PkgDB
            .Where(extPkg => tag.Value == extPkg.PkgGuid.ToString())
            .Where(extPkg => RequiredGuidExtensions.Contains(extPkg.TemplateVersion))
            .Count() == extensionsCount
    select new
    {
        RootGuid = tag.PkgGuid,
        ExtTemplateGuids = DBContext.PkgDB
            .Where(extPkg => tag.Value == extPkg.PkgGuid.ToString())
            .Select(extPkg.TemplateVersion)
            .ToList()
    }
```

Note that query will show correct result only if `RequiredGuidExtensions` is unique set of GUIDs.

Comment: I tried your example but it still won't work like this. I tried adding a tolist and it will say that the query can't be translated...

Comment: Rewrite your question and post real classes and how you prepare `examples`. Specify ORM version.

Comment: Any idea how to create examples that will replicate the behaviour since when done on c# it works and only breaks with iqueryables?

Comment: Because EF `IQueryable` has a lot of limitations. It should be translatable to the SQL. You have hidden all important parts from the question.

Comment: I see your problem - `group by` and even worse - Eager Loading. Next step is to add REAL classes used in query.

Comment: I'm starting to think I'd be better off just asking what I'm trying to do instead of fixing what I already tried. Let me add a bit of context around that.

Comment: Actually I can predict what you are trying to do. But without classes I cannot create effective query.

Comment: I added the relevant parts of the classes. If you want I can post the complete ones. I added a bit of context at the beginning of the question